# Bulk Reverse DNS query with DIG

Tags: dns, dig

I want to do a bulk reverse DNS query to a specific nameserver.

Currently, after searching here and Google. I got it to work for 1 entry at the time with the following command:

```
dig @NAMESERVER -x 10.10.10.10 +short
```

This returns exactly what I want. But If I want to do this for multiple IP addresses, it fails. What I did was to make a list of 2 IP addresses to test.

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
dig @NAMESERVER -x -f dnsquery.txt +short
```

This does not show any result, what am I doing wrong?

The input files has 2 lines, each with 1 IP address:

```
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.11
```

Comment: You'll probably want to covert the `a.b.c.d` to the reverse `d.c.b.a.in-addr.arpa` and then do `PTR ...` lookups, or use a loop around `dig` that calls `-x a.b.c.d` for each IP.

Comment: Ho do I do a loop, sorry newbie here....

Answer (score 1):

As thrig mentioned, you could loop the `dig` call.

You can use for example this little bash script ans save it in a file called e.g. `bulkreverse.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='ip_in.txt' # name of file with IPs to handle
nameserver='8.8.8.8' # nameserver to query

for ip in `cat $filename`
do
echo 'Handling reverse DNS for $ip'
dig @$nameserver -x $ip +short
done
```

The variable `filename` specifies the name of the file with the list of IP addresses (like you example, oen IP per line). `nameserver` is the nameserver to query.

If you saved the script in a file called `bulkreverse.sh` you need to make it executable by running

```
chmod +x bulkreverse.sh
```

After that you can execute it with

```
./bulkreverse.sh
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot then GNU Parallel may help speed up the processing:

```
nameserver=80.80.81.81
parallel -j100 --retries 3 dig @$nameserver -x {} +short :::: ip_in.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to convert the forwards addresses to reverse ones, and then pipe the result to `dig`

```
awk -F. '{printf "%s.%s.%s.%s.in-addr.arpa\n",$4,$3,$2,$1}' dnsqueries.txt |
    dig +short ptr @NAMESERVER -f -
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`prips`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/prips.1.html), you can use it for bulk reverse DNS queries using [CIDR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632) notation:

```
prips 192.0.2.0/24 | xargs -I{} dig @1.1.1.1 +noall +answer -x {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your original code didn't work is because the `-x` needs to be included in each line of data read from the file. This is documented in the man page, but I personally think it could be clearer:

> **`-f file`** Batch mode: `dig` reads a list of lookup requests to process from the given file. Each line in the file should be organized in the same way they would be presented as queries to `dig` using the command-line interface.

The last sentence is the explainer, that lines must be "*organized in the same way they would be presented as queries to dig*". In other words, your example file would need to contain this:

```
-x 10.10.10.10
-x 10.10.10.11
```

Assuming your file is invariant we can then use `sed` to prepend the necessary `-x` and then pipe the result to `dig`:

```
sed 's/^/-x /' dnsquery.txt | dig +short -f -
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Github project that performs the bulk reverse DNS query. You can see that project [here](https://github.com/g33kyrash/mass-reverse-dns).

Comment: Perhaps you could extend this answer from being only a link to describe how the OP would obtain, configure, install, and use this project to solve their problem?